Problem with a custom activation function - TypeError: argument of type 'Bind' is not iterable
I am building auto-encoder and I want to encode my values into a logical matrix. I'm using my custom step activation function in the last layer as below:
@tf.custom_gradient
def binary_activation(x):

    ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
    zeros = tf.zeros(tf.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)

    def grad(dy):
        return ...  # TODO define gradient
  return keras.backend.switch(x > 0.5, ones, zeros), grad

However, after running few episodes, it will show error:

I am not sure about this error. Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you

The error message you're encountering, "TypeError: argument of type 'Bind' is not iterable," isn't directly related to the code you provided. It likely stems from a different part of your program. However, the custom activation function might contribute to training issues in your autoencoder if the gradient isn't defined correctl.Try this **# Gradient is 1 for positive values (x > threshold) and 0 for negative values
return tf.where(x > 0.5, ones, zeros) * dy
Apply the activation and return with the gradient function
return keras.backend.switch(x > 0.5, ones, zeros), grad**.
